# How can I handle large files processing via messaging queries in Microservices environment?

Tags: java, jms, ipc, microservices

Many people suggest that the good way for organizing IPC (ImicroservicesC) is asynchronous communication via queries like Kafka and JMS.

But what if I need to pass large data files between services?

Suppose I have a Video Microservice and a Publisher Microservice. The first one receives videos from the user, verifies and sends them to Publisher for converting and publishing. It's oblivious video can be a very large file and it can overload messaging system (Kafka is not suitable for big messages at all). Of course, I can share one database for them and send video_id via Kafka, but it couples these services and its not a real microservices architecture anymore.

Do you have similar situations in practice? How do you handle it?

Thanks

Comment: This probably belongs on [programmers.se]

Comment: @JimGarrison: This question doesn't seem answerable in its present form.

Comment: I agree it's borderline but I see a kernel of a useful question (how to handle large messages in a microservices environment).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an Enterprise Integration Pattern from the book by Hohpe/Wolfe called the [Claim Check Pattern](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/StoreInLibrary.html) that addresses these concerns.

Essentially the big blob is removed from the message and stored somewhere that both sender and receiver can access, whether that be a common file share, FTP server, an Amazon S3 blob, whatever. It leaves a "claim check" behind: some sort of address that describes how to find the blob back.

The tiny message can then be transmitted over Kafka/JMS, or some other message queue system, most of which are fairly bad at dealing with large data blobs.

Of course, a very simple implementation is to leave the files on a file share and only refer to them by file path.

It's more complex when it's preferable to have the blob integrated with the rest of the message, requiring a true Claim Check implementation. This can be handled at an infrastructure level so the message sender and receiver don't need to know any of the details behind how the data is transmitted.

I know that you're in the Java landscape, but in [NServiceBus](http://particular.net/nservicebus) (I work for [Particular Software](http://particular.net/), the makers of NServiceBus) this pattern is implemented with the [Data Bus feature](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/messaging/databus) in a message pipeline step. All the developer needs to do is identify what type of message properties apply to the data bus, and (in the default file share implementation) configure the location where files are stored. Developers are also free to provide their own data bus implementation.

One thing to keep in mind is that with the blobs disconnected from the messages, you have to provide for cleanup. If the messages are one-way, you could clean them up as soon as the message is successfully processed. With Kafka (not terribly familiar) there's a possibility to process messages from a stream multiple times, correct? If so you'd want to wait until it was no longer possible to process that message. Or, if the Publish/Subscribe pattern is use, you would not want to clean up the files until you were sure all subscribers had a chance to be processed. In order to accomplish that, you'd need to set an SLA (a timespan that each message must be processed within) on the message and clean up the blob storage after that timespan had elapsed.

In any case, lots of things to consider, which make it much more useful to implement at an infrastructure level rather than try to roll your own in each instance.